# When threads are created, do they run in parallel or concurrently?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I’m learning about multi threading and I understand the difference between parallelism and concurrency. My question is, if I create a second thread and detach it from the parent thread, do these 2 run concurrently or in parallel?

Comment: What is the difference, in your view, between running in parallel and running concurrently?  How many cores does your machine have?

Comment: From my readings, concurrently means the 2 threads are contexting switching between each other while parallel means they run simultaneously. So let’s say I have a 2 cores and I create 2 threads. Will they run in parallel automatically or will they start concurrently? Sorry if dumb question, just trying to understand

Comment: I guess another question is, when creating another thread on a machine with 2 cores, is it automatically created on the second core?

Comment: That has nothing to do with C or C++ itself and everything to do with whatever operating system and hardware you're running on. C or C++ does not define how thread behave.

Comment: It depends on the o/s and various scheduling options etc, but in general, they will run in parallel, subject to the observation that other processes on the system also share the cores, so there'll also be concurrency some of the time.  Where the second thread is scheduled depends on the o/s etc.  Since the threads share memory, it can be disadvantageous for them to be on different CPUs in a multi-CPU machine — if the system has NUMA and so on.  There are many, many factors that influence the scheduling of threads.  But, in general, they will run in parallel.

Comment: You can't know or control that.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Thats totally wrong! Every OS provides methods to pick a specific core for a thread  ( linux: pthread_setaffinity_np... ). In combination with priority settings, maybe using an RT features or extensions ) you can control execution of a thread very granular as long your wishes are possible on the given hardware.

Comment: @Klaus yes, the OS. Not C++.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Which means you control it... via a library call.

Answer (score 2):

Typically (for a modern OS) there's about 100 processes with maybe an average of 2 threads each for a total of 200 threads just for background services, GUI, software updaters, etc. You start your process (1 more thread) and it spawns its second thread, so now there's 202 threads.

Out of those 202 threads almost all of them will be blocked waiting for something to happen most of the time. If 30 threads are not blocked, and you have 8 CPUs, then 30 threads compete for those 8 CPUs.

If 30 threads compete for 8 CPUs, then maybe 4 threads are high priority and get a whole CPU for themselves and 10 threads are low priority and don't get any CPU time because there's more important work for CPUs to do; and maybe 12 threads are medium priority and share 4 CPUs by time multiplexing (frequently switching between threads). How this actually works depends on the OS and its scheduler (its very different for different operating systems).

Of course the number of threads and their priorities changes often (e.g. as threads are created and terminated), and threads block and unblock very often, so how many threads are competing for CPUs (not blocked) is constantly changing. Maybe there's 30 threads competing for 8 CPUs at one point in time, and 2 milliseconds later there's 5 threads and 3 CPUs are idle.

> My question is, if I create a second thread and detach it from the parent thread, do these 2 run concurrently or in parallel?

Yes; your 2 threads may either run concurrently (share a CPU with time multiplexing) or run in parallel (on different CPUs); and can do both at different times (concurrently for a while, then parallel for a while, then..).

Answer (score 1):

> if I create a second thread and detach it...

Detach is not something your program can do to a thread. It's merely something the program can do to a `std::thread` *object.* The object is not the thread. The object is just a handle that your program can use to talk about the thread, and "detach" just grants permission for the program to destroy the handle, while the thread continues to run.

> ...from the parent thread

So, "detach" doesn't detach one thread from another (e.g., a "child" from its "parent,") It detaches a thread from its `std::thread` handle.

FYI: Most programming environments do not recognize any parent/child relationship between threads. If thread A creates thread B, that does not give thread A any special privileges or capabilities with respect to thread B that threads C, D, and E don't also have.

That's not to say that *you* can't recognize the relationship. It might mean something in *your* program. It just doesn't mean anything to the OS.

> ...Parallel or concurrently

That's not an either-or choice. Parallel *is* concurrent.

"Concurrency" does not mean "threads context switching." Rather, it's a statement about the order in which the threads access and update shared variables.

When two threads run concurrently on typical multiprocessing hardware, their actions will be *serializable.* That means that the outcome of the program will be the same *as if* some single, imaginary thread did all the same things that the real program threads did, and it did them one-by-one, in some particular order.

Two threads are concurrent with each other if the serialization is *non-deterministic.* That is to say, if the "particular order" in which the things all seem to happen is not entirely determined by the program. They are concurrent if different runs of the program can behave *as if* the imaginary single thread chose different serializations.

There's also a simpler test, which usually amounts to the same thing: Two threads *probably* are concurrent with each other if both threads are started before either one of them finishes.

Any way you look at it though, if two threads are truly running in parallel with each other, then they must also be *concurrent* with each other.

> *Do* they run in parallel?

@Brendan already answered that one. TLDR: if the computer has more than one CPU, then they potentially *can* run in parallel. How much of the time they actually spend running in parallel depends on many things though, and many of those things are in the domain of the operating system.